# Visual Studio Windows Form Designer sometimes makes unrelated minor changes by itself

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

When comparing the changes made to the Designer Code after having made a change in Designer (in Design mode), I sometimes find that Designer has also made other minor and unrelated changes.

The most common would be that it has either added or removed a decimal point from every font size eg.:

```
New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8!)
```

becomes

```
New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.0!)
```

or vice-versa (depending on what the original started out as).

It sometimes will also change the case of the first character of Boolean properties
eg. 'True' becomes 'true'.

The result is that you have to skip over all of these frivolous changes to find the real changes which is especially frustrating during a code review.

Does anyone know how to stop this, please?

Visual Studio 2013 (VB.NET WinForms)

Comment: This has been the case since Day 1.

Comment: This will only get better when you stop reviewing code that was auto-generated by a tool.  Simply exclude the *.Designer.vb source code files, there's nothing to see there.  Getting all devs to use compatible video adapter settings and Windows preferences is a long-distance second solution.  Not actually a good idea, you want to know what can go wrong when your clients also use different settings.

Comment: The Designer.vb files are not "auto-generated". That would suggest that they are redundant, and that there is a source file from which they can be generated. What makes them different is that they are (usually) edited using the Windows Forms Designer. This tool is fundamentally broken, given that it can add hundreds of unrelated and unnecessary changes in addition to your own. But this could hypothetically have been the case for _any_ type of source file. So, no, they should _not_ be excluded from code review.